# Drupal hook to create module menu

Tags: drupal, menu, hook, anchor

I am trying to find a way for my module, upon installation, to create an anchor link.

**My current strategy is to create a custom menu, similar to and located with the primary, secondary etc menus.**
***Within this menu I want to have a one or more links defined by my module***. Then I would hope that my custom menu will automatiaclly have a block which users can position anywhere they please.

When my module is un-installed, I want the menu and it's links removed.

Can anyone please give me some pointers to accomplish this?

Comment: @siski, I was just looking through my old answers to unanswered questions and wondered if you'd solved this? If not, let me know so I can improve my answer/help further.

Answer (score 11):

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7

```
/**
 * Implement hook_menu()
 */
function <module>_menu() {

  $items = array();
  $items['admin/<path>'] = array(
    'title' => '<Link title>',
    'description' => '<Link description>',
    'page callback' => '<function from your module>',
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'weight' => 15,
    'menu_name' => 'primary-links'
  );
  return $items;
}
```

'menu_name' will put the links in the relevant menu

Update: To create the menu first you must use either `hook_install` or `hook_enable` which will run actions on first install, or enable respectively.

```
/**
 * Implement hook_install()
 */
 function <module>_install () {
    $menu = array(
        'menu_name' => 'test-menu',
        'title' => 'Test menu',
        'description' => 'A test menu'
    );

    menu_save($menu);
    cache_clear_all('*', 'cache_menu', TRUE);

    drupal_set_message($message = t('The module was successfully installed. '), $type = 'status');
}
```

The above code will create a menu.

Note: for [hook_install()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--install.php/function/hook_install/6) to run you must first disable and then uninstall your module before reenabling. use [hook_enable()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_enable/7) to run it every time.

You can then use the above `hook_menu()` description to add an item to that menu programatically. `menu_name` in both arrays must match obviously.

Having read your comment and found that you need to create your menu, not add to an existing one, it may be better for me to suggest using [menu_link_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_link_save/7) instead in the `hook_install()` call.

Note that you will also need to use [hook_disable()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_disable/7) or [hook_uninstall()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--install.php/function/hook_uninstall/6) in order to remove the menu link afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, I will try your approach asap. And the down vote did not come from me :-)

Comment: @sisko no problem. Hope you get it sorted- if not you know where to ask :) coracho, thanks!

Comment: Hey Ben, I tried your suggested solution but it is not exactly what I am trying to achieve. I need to create a custom menu call "simple-menu" and within that set a single link called "simple-link". Also, perhaps you can also help by telling me if when I click "simple-link" I have target one of my module's hooks?? Really hope someone can help .... thanks!

Comment: Hi sisko, I've amended my answer to show you how to create a menu first. You don't have to target a hook function I believe- I think you can use the array key 'page callback' and pass it a path. This may not be 100% correct though as I've not tested it.

Comment: +1 for remembering to include the menu creation, I just spent some time googling this and a lot of people neglect to include or just point to the examples module